# View the constraints enforced on a table- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Since I am not much of a DB guy, I have a query.I use Mysql.
I am given a table which has around 12 columns and that table has a PRIMARY key,UNIQUE & a FOREIGN key defined.

Is there a way to find on which columns the constraints are defined?

I came across one query:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM tablt_name;
```

But It does not give a clear idea, only the primary key column is displayed by the above query.

If there is any other way to get the info, pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like thisL

```
USE information_schema; 

SELECT table_name, 
       column_name, 
       constraint_name, 
       referenced_table_name, 
       referenced_column_name 
FROM   key_column_usage 
WHERE  table_schema = "" 
       AND table_name = "" 
       AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```
DESCRIBE table_name
```

Comment: Thanx...I too got it. In fact ur previous edit with 'SHOW' keyword helped me recollect it